# How do I read a JSON file and save the data in variables using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
   "code":100,
   "data":{
      "month":[
         {
            "yearText":"2011",
            "months":[
               {
                  "monthText":"6",
                  "days":[
                     {
                        "dayText":"13",
                        "cios":[
                           {
                              "status":"continues",
                              "start":"23:00:00",
                              "end":"23:59:59",
                              "id":12
                           }
                        ],
                        "bois":[
                           {
                              "status":"continues",
                              "start":"23:30:00",
                              "end":"23:59:59",
                              "id":12
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "dayText":"14",
                        "cios":[
                           {
                              "status":"continued",
                              "start":"00:00:00",
                              "end":"01:00:00",
                              "id":12
                           },
                           {
                              "status":"within",
                              "start":"11:42:14",
                              "end":"11:43:45",
                              "id":11
                           }
                        ],
                        "bois":[
                           {
                              "status":"continued",
                              "start":"00:00:00",
                              "end":"00:30:00",
                              "id":12
                           },
                           {
                              "status":"within",
                              "start":"11:42:39",
                              "end":"11:43:33",
                              "id":11
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "next":"\/attendance\/get-history\/2011\/07",
      "previous":"\/attendance\/get-history\/2011\/05"
   },
   "msg":"Attendance history of John Doe on June, 2011."
}
```

I need to read that file which is "attendance.json" and save the data as variables using jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "save the data as variables"?

Comment: Does the URL to this file violate Same Origin Policy? Is this returned via JSONP?

Comment: Phil - by save the data as variables i meant that i wanted to save the json objects as javascript variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a [getJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: Can you say a bit more on this ? I tried the following code but it doesn't work      ``` $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){return data}) ```` but this is not working. Essentially I'm trying to assign a variable to the contents of the JSON file to be used in other functions. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean or why you've included the `PHP` tag but provided the `attendance.json` file is in the same domain as your JavaScript (Google "Same Origin Policy") ...

```
$.getJSON('attendance.json', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // data contains your JSON object
    alert(data.code); // 100
});
```

For an external data source (separate domain), this is only possible if the remote server supports a JSONP request.

Otherwise, you could try fetching the data server-side (PHP)

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/attendance.json'));
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @hilarl Mind explaining why you re-assigned the accepted answer?